# import Vue from 'vue' как работает

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь понять логику `import`. Почему для всего остального я пишу полные пути, а для `vue - import Vue from 'vue'`, вместо какого нибудь `import Vue from '/node_modules/vue...'` Почему это работает так. Чувствую что вопрос тупой и какой-то очевидный, но не могу найти ответа

Comment: поиск в папке `node_modules` идет по умолчанию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Vue установлен через `npm install`, и лежит в корне папки `node_modules`

Comment: это сообщение не является ответом на поставленный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Либо как сказал @Денис, либо на странице, на которой ты запускаешь vue приложение, прописано вручную

```js
<script type="importmap">
{ "imports": {
    "vue":        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.37/vue.esm-browser.min.js",
    "vue-router": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/4.0.16/vue-router.esm-browser.min.js"
} }
</script>
```